# Slow MySQL (InnoDB) query despite join on indexed key, why?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Do you have any idea why this request could be slow (1.7 s on a otherwise fast MySQL server):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_A.keyA 
FROM TABLE_A,TABLE_B 
WHERE TABLE_A.keyB= TABLE_B.keyB 
AND TABLE_A.fieldC in (0,2,5,7,8) LIMIT 20;
```

With this execution plan given by `EXPLAIN`:

```
id    select_type table       type    possible_keys         key                   key_len   ref     rows     Extra 
1     SIMPLE      TABLE_B     index   PRIMARY               PRIMARY               8     NULL      10     Using index; Using temporary
1     SIMPLE      TABLE_A     ref     IDX_TABLE_A_KEY_B     IDX_TABLE_A_KEY_B     8     TABLE_B.keyB     25455     Using where
```

Other elements :

- the table TABLE_A has 300 000 lines
- TABLE_A.keyA is the primary key of TABLE_A
- TABLE_A.keyB is a foreign key towards the primary key keyB of TABLE_B ; 
  the table TABLE_B has 10 lines ;
- 99 % of TABLE_A has fieldC=1 and 1 % of the table has fieldC in (0,2,5,7,8) (that is why this field is not indexed ; EDIT this clause is not problematic because a SELECT with the same clause but no join with TABLE_B is fast) ;
- it seems to me that it is the JOIN that is guilty, because a simple SELECT on the table is fast ;
- a join with another table TABLE_C is also very slow ;
- MySQL version : 5.1.23a-maria-alpha

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 99 % of TABLE_A has fieldC=1 and 1 % of the table has fieldC in (0,2,5,7,8) (that is why this field is not indexed

That would be an excellent reason to index the column.
Your query only wants less than 1% of the table, so an index would be very selective.

Comment: You're right. However, each new line of the table has this field updated 10 times (it is a status) before it has its last value. Won't this lead to a time-consuming update of the index ?

Comment: Of course it takes (a little) time to update the index (and some disk space to store it). But the index makes the query faster. This is a trade-off.

Comment: It was that. The SELECT time decreased down to 0,0012 seconds !

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `IN` clause, they tend to be quite slow, have you got an index on `TABLE_A.fieldC`?

Comment: As I added later, the same request with no join but the same IN clause is fast.

Comment: Without the join it is a different query!  You can't compare them for speed.  Try adding an index on fieldC if you really need to improve this.

Comment: Great, it was indeed that, see answer to Thilo !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_A.keyA 
FROM TABLE_A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.keyB = TABLE_B.keyB 
WHERE 
TABLE_A.fieldC IN (0, 2, 5, 7, 8) LIMIT 20;
```

Try that one out.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_A.keyA 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE TABLE_A.keyB IN (SELECT TABLE_B.keyB FROM TABLE_B )
AND TABLE_A.fieldC in (0,2,5,7,8) LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add index on column fieldC.
Then run the query

```
Select DISTINCT keyA from 
 (select keyA, keyB from TABLE_A where fieldC in (0,2,5,7,8)) 
as temp STRAIGHT_JOIN TABLE_B on temp.keyB=TABLE_B.keyB limit 20
```

Try with straight join and inner join.

Comment: Right for the index (see Thilo), but I cannot change the way the request is written.